# How can I browse community wiki posts?

Tags: support, search, community-wiki

How can I browse all the questions that are of type 'community wiki'?

There are great wiki questions, but it seems the only way to find these questions is to filter by highly voted questions, or highly 'favorited' questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-community-wiki-questions

Answer (score 7):

**Method #1 - Use Google**

For example for Stack Overflow, type the following query into [Google](http://google.com):

> `site:stackoverflow.com "community wiki" OR "community-wiki"`

That Google query will show you any post that has the word "Community Wiki" (which all community wiki posts have).  I tried to post it as a hyperlink, but `+`   gets inserted into all the spaces on the hyperlink, rendering the link useless.

I normally despise GIYF answers, but in this case, the Google search is much better than Stack Overflow's search for finding stuff on... Stack Overflow. Go figure.

**Method #2 - Use the built-in per site Search**

The built in search on any site appears to also be able to find posts. You can use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=community+wiki) for example, or just type "Community Wiki" into the search bar on the upper-right hand side of the page to search.

Comment: That link comes out garbled on my machine - with +'s instead of some of the spaces. This is what I changed it to (pasted from addr bar): http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%2B%22community+wiki%22+OR+%22community-wiki%22&btnG=Search&meta=

Comment: Horrors, a GIYF answer! Must downvote!

Answer (score 7):

Type this is the search box (upper right) on any Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange page to browse the list of all community wiki questions:

> wiki:1 is:question

You can apply other filters than just for Community Wiki. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37652/where-can-i-see-the-list-of-new-community-wiki-questions/37726#37726) for some examples.

Comment: This is not correct. See the link in the comment in the question

Comment: @Downvoter: what is it that is not working? It may not work for *searching*, but for *browsing* (approximately 98000 CW posts on Stack Overflow) I think it works fine.

Comment: that also returns **answers**, not only **questions** as the OP is asking

Comment: @jmfsg I just added `is:question` to give what I think is now the precise answer that was sought.