# Where can I see the list of new community wiki questions?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

I've been using Stack Overflow for the past six months and I try to answer many community wiki questions.

- Where can I see list of recent community wiki questions?
- Why there isn't a wiki tab under questions?
- Where can I find a list of highest voted community wiki questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki:1 (You can sort it by clicking the tabs), or enter wiki:1 in the search box.

There isn't a tab, most likely because community wiki questions aren't really displayed much differently than any other question.

I find just the highest questions of all time to be just as (or more) useful as a list of the highest community wiki questions.

Comment: The current tabs: newest, featured, hot, votes and active are only filters/sortings. Having a filter for wiki as a tab should be no different, and useful if you need it. I don't understand why the only way you can filter on wiki questions is by advanced search parameter.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Chacha102's answer and also directly answering the third question:

You can apply various filters. Besides "wiki" they are: "hasaccepted", "closed", "answers" and "votes". There is also "user", but it is not so interesting in this context.

There is also a way to filter for a particular tag, the "[*tag*]" syntax. E.g. [perl] to only display questions tagged with "perl".

Examples (enter in the search box in the upper right on any page):

This example is also an answer to the third question. To list highly voted Community Wiki (CW) questions that have not been closed (100 votes in this example - result takes up 2 pages for Stack Overflow):

> **wiki:1 closed:0 votes:100**

To list CW questions that have not been closed:

> **wiki:1 closed:0**

To list CW questions that have not been closed, have at least 7 upvotes and no accepted answer:

> **wiki:1 closed:0 votes:7 hasaccepted:0**

To list CW questions that have not been closed, have at least 3 upvotes and have no answers:

> **wiki:1 closed:0 votes:3 answers:0**

To list CW questions that have not been closed, and have at least 12 answers:

> **wiki:1 closed:0 answers:12**

To list CW questions tagged with Perl that have not been closed, and have no answers:

> **wiki:1 closed:0 answers:0 [perl]**

This can be expressed as URLs. E.g. for the third example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+closed%3A0+votes%3A7+hasaccepted%3A0
```

These filters were described in an old Stack Overflow blog entry: [Stack Overflow Search – Now 61% Less Crappy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/). The filters are documented in `/search` and are more up to date, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search for Stack Overflow. There is a new filter: `intitle` ("questions with specific words in the title").

---

Illustration:

[alt text http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/SO/SearchFilters_2010-01-31.png](http://www.pil.sdu.dk/1/until2039-12-31/SO/SearchFilters_2010-01-31.png)

Comment: This content should be in the FAQ.

Comment: question:1 seems to also work, to only match questions rather than all posts.

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems obscure, even for a site focused on programmers.