# Is there a way to search for community wiki 'questions'?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, search

I tried a search, but I get answers also in the results.
I'd like to search only questions.

I tried: `wiki:1 question:1` (shot in the dark) but it didn't work, I still get answers in the results.

In contrast, perhaps a way to search only answers would be useful too

So I propose the `question` and `answer` search operator to combine [with the rest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37652/where-can-i-see-the-list-of-new-community-wiki-questions

Comment: Near as I can tell, the answers to the question fretje links to effectively answer this.

Comment: @Shog, @fretje, how could you search for questions that are wiki, excluding answers, using the info on that link?

Comment: @Dow: You're right, I now understand what exactly you want, and I think it's already possible (see my answer).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Was thinking of the wiki:1 answers:1 search, but this is a bit different - fretje's answer here seems like a solid solution though.

Comment: @Shog, @fre, thanks... sorry if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use

```
wiki:1 views:1 apples oranges
```

Then the search results will only return questions which contain apples or oranges (answers don't have views).

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to do this now is `wiki:yes` (or `wiki:1`) and `is:question`, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki:yes%20is:question).