# Search only for community-wiki threads

Tags: support, tags, community-wiki, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to search for community wiki ‘questions’?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-community-wiki-questions)

How can I search for community-wiki questions *only*?

I thought I could use the [community-wiki] tag, but that only resulted in 4 posts.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-community-wiki-questions

Comment: @Shog9: excellent...well, I finally had to come up with the search `meta:1 search wiki` to get your post to show up. I had 34 pages of `community-wiki search` results. After the first 2 pages...I was done. I guess it would be a stoopud question to ask if there are detailed instructions on using this search pattern? It would certainly increase the value of the results returned on my searches.

Comment: Well, you can check this out: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/

Comment: @Shog9: yeah I finally found that too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search `wiki:1` to see all community-wiki posts.

Comment: +1 @waiwai933: this saved me a lot of work for the search `wiki:1 pattern`. I could have been here all day...or else I'd have stoopudly started a dupe.

Comment: This is wrong, that search will also return answers, check the link provided by Shog9

Comment: @MrStatic: he answered before Shog9, there is no evidence whatsoever that he was aware of the dupe or that he was ill intentioned.