# Looking for community wiki posts

Tags: support, search, community-wiki

Okay - I'm quite new to Stack Overflow (et.all). Is there a way to search for the questions/answers marked community wiki?

I don't always know what I'm looking for - sometimes I'm just lurking to get new insight, and many of the posts, I've stumbled upon so far marked community wiki have been great, so for me it would make great sense to find all community wiki posts for a given Tag.

Make sense?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-community-wiki-questions

Comment: thanks - missed that searching.